# multicolumn environment with columns of different height

Tags: multicol

I'm looking for a version of `multicols` environment which allows the columns to have different heights.  The goal is to make the outmost column several lines shorter *from the top*, so that the running head would fill that space (as in the attached image which I made through hacking the existing `multicols`, but I cannot avoid side-effects).

Do we have some tool for that?

Thank you in advance

[image: An example of what I need]

Comment: If you turn off column balancing then that would probably not require too many changes in multicol, to balance the last page while leaving three lines in the final column would require more extensive changes I would guess.