# \rightmark not working as expected on a page with multiple flowframes

Tags: flowfram, mark

I’m trying to typeset a dictionary and I’m having trouble getting `\rightmark` to work correctly with `flowfram`.

To illustrate, here’s a simplified version of my setup:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth  = 148mm,
    paperheight = 210mm,
    top         = 10mm,
    bottom      = 10mm,
    left        = 10mm,
    right       = 10mm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{flowfram}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark}

\newflowframe{0.48\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe{0.48\textwidth}{\textheight}{0.52\textwidth}{0pt}

\newcommand\headword[1]{%
    \paragraph{#1}%
    \markboth{#1}{#1}%
}
\newcommand\definition{%
    bla bla bla bla bla,
    bla bla bla bla bla,
    bla bla bla bla bla
}

\begin{document}

\headword{aa} \definition

\headword{ab} \definition

\headword{ac} \definition

\headword{ad} \definition

\headword{ae} \definition

\headword{af} \definition

\headword{ag} \definition

\headword{ah} \definition

\headword{ai} \definition

\headword{aj} \definition

\headword{ak} \definition

\headword{al} \definition

\headword{am} \definition

\headword{an} \definition

\headword{ao} \definition

\headword{ap} \definition

\headword{aq} \definition

\headword{ar} \definition

\headword{as} \definition

\headword{at} \definition

\headword{au} \definition

\headword{av} \definition

\headword{aw} \definition

\headword{ax} \definition

\headword{ay} \definition

\headword{az} \definition

\headword{ba} \definition

\headword{bb} \definition

\headword{bc} \definition

\headword{bd} \definition

\headword{be} \definition

\headword{bf} \definition

\headword{bg} \definition

\headword{bh} \definition

\headword{bi} \definition

\headword{bj} \definition

\headword{bk} \definition

\headword{bl} \definition

\headword{bm} \definition

\headword{bn} \definition

\headword{bo} \definition

\headword{bp} \definition

\headword{bq} \definition

\headword{br} \definition

\headword{bs} \definition

\headword{bt} \definition

\headword{bu} \definition

\headword{bv} \definition

\headword{bw} \definition

\headword{bx} \definition

\headword{by} \definition

\headword{bz} \definition

\end{document}
```

I’m trying to set up my project so that

- The header on an even page displays the first headword on the page (`\rightmark`)
- The header on an odd page displays the last headword on the page (`\leftmark`)

[image: PDF output]

As you can see, the header on page 1 shows ‘bb’ as expected. However, on page 2, I’m getting ‘bq’ (the first headword in the second flowframe) instead of the expected ‘bc’ (the first headword on the entire page). The second flowframe seems to ‘reset’ or ‘override’ the marks in the first flowframe.

Is this a bug with `flowfram`?

Basically, I want to access the first mark in the first flowframe on a page with multiple flowframes. Is this possible?

(I know `multicol` probably looks like a better solution here, but I prefer using `flowfram` because of its support for floats and [different column heights](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494924/multicolumn-environment-with-columns-of-different-height).)

Comment: It doesn't look as if flowframe correctly restore the marks, but I'm not sure if I would call it a bug, you seem to misuse the package for a document type it is not meant to. Write the author and ask.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t mean to sound rude. I should have phrased my question more carefully.